# Importing data from public Google spreadsheet into SSIS?

Tags: ssis, google-api, kingswaysoft

I have been tasked with importing a google spreadsheet (which is public and accessible to everyone) into our data warehouse for analysis. I am just struggling on where to start? I have tried a a trial of Kingswaysoft which has a Google sheets component and this worked, however I need something I can build myself which won't cost anything.

Does anyone have any advice on how I could achieve this? As the spreadsheet is public, would I still need to provide the google account details when writing the script?

Many thanks for any help

Tried Kingswaysoft component, worked fine but was only a trial
Also found some tutorials online but these were from 2010 and I think the google API changed since

I expect to have an SSIS package which when run, exports the data from the spreadsheet into a table in my SQL server database.

Comment: I'd start with a conversation with your supervisor about the costs of reinventing the wheel. Then once you've demonstrated that one day of your time will probably cost more than this addon, and you'll probably need 6 months to reinvent the wheel... you should go with with Kingswaysoft.